# unable to run rspec test with firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, firefox, rspec, capybara

Any idea with below error? I am not able to run my rspec test on firefox.

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
       Could not find Firefox binary (os=macosx). Make sure Firefox is installed or set the path manually with Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=

```
Gemfile
gem "capybara", :git => "git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git"
gem "capybara-firebug"
```

```
capybara.rb
require 'capybara/firebug'
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.firebug_version = '1.8.4'
```

```
spec_helper.rb
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_with_firebug if example.metadata[:firebug]
```

I found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/1031029) bug didn't helped me much to fix this bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake, I didn't reloaded the terminal after this configuration.